# Filtering an Array with another Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react, and I'm working on a product where I am trying to get the products and their details from my `products` array with the products within my cart filtered out. I've tried doing this a couple of ways, but I'm struggling to get this to work. I have:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Product from '../components/Product';
import {Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';


 export default function CarouselForProductPage(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const { loading, error, products } = productList;
    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
    const { cartItems } = cart;
    useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(listProducts({}));
    }, [dispatch]);

    
    var cart_ids = cartItems.map(product => ({ _id: product._id }));
     console.log(cart_ids);

    let res = products.filter(x => !cart_ids.includes(x));
    console.log(res);

   var carts = products.filter((x) => x._id !== cart_ids);
   console.log(carts);

    
  return (
    <div>
        
    </div>
  );
}
```

My `cartItems` variable is an array of the data of the products in my cart, and `cart_ids` are the ids associated with those products. The variable `products` list all of the data associate with each of my products. I'm trying to filter out the products from `products` that have the ids contained within `cart_ids`. I have tried doing this two different ways:

```
let res = products.filter(x => !cart_ids.includes(x));
    console.log(res);
```

And

```
   var carts = products.filter((x) => x._id !== cart_ids);
   console.log(carts);
```

Both of these arrays (res and carts) are giving me results equal to the `products` array.

I would really appreciate any help or guidance on what I am doing wrong.Thank you!

```
cart_ids = [
0:
_id: "622ae8d94bee11259a3b1756"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
_id: "624bc1a50f91078261ab650d"
[[Prototype]]: Object
]
```

```
products = 
[0:
image: "/uploads/2022-03-11T06:15:00.618Zproduct-1.jpg"
name: "Bliss"
price: 40
__v: 5
_id: "622ae8d94bee11259a3b1756"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
image: "/uploads/2022-03-12T23:31:14.922Zproduct-2.jpg"
name: "sample name 1647127866131"
price: 30
__v: 1
_id: "622d2d3a4bee11259a3b17ed"
[[Prototype]]: Object
2:
image: "/uploads/2022-04-05T04:12:46.469Zproduct-4.jpg"
name: "sample name 1649131941926"
price: 50
__v: 1
_id: "624bc1a50f91078261ab650d"
[[Prototype]]: Object
3:
image: "/uploads/2022-04-05T04:39:38.449Zproduct-1.jpg"
name: "sample name 1649133566290"
price: 60
__v: 1
_id: "624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529"
[[Prototype]]: Object
4:
image: "/uploads/2022-04-05T04:40:31.140Zproduct-5.jpg"
name: "sample name 1649133604220"
price: 40
__v: 1
_id: "624bc8240f91078261ab6531"]
```

Result I am trying to get

```
[[0:
image: "/uploads/2022-03-12T23:31:14.922Zproduct-2.jpg"
name: "sample name 1647127866131"
price: 30
__v: 1
_id: "622d2d3a4bee11259a3b17ed"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
image: "/uploads/2022-04-05T04:39:38.449Zproduct-1.jpg"
name: "sample name 1649133566290"
price: 60
__v: 1
_id: "624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529"
[[Prototype]]: Object
2:
image: "/uploads/2022-04-05T04:40:31.140Zproduct-5.jpg"
name: "sample name 1649133604220"
price: 40
__v: 1
_id: "624bc8240f91078261ab6531"]]
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Osamu_Renji HI, I edited my question and added what ```cart_ids, products, and result I would like to get``` are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cart_ids is an array of objects you need to parse to a string array first to use for `includes`.

const cardIdOnlyArray = cartIds.map(x => x._id)

```js
const products = [
  {
    image: '/uploads/2022-03-11T06:15:00.618Zproduct-1.jpg',
    name: 'Bliss',
    price: 40,
    __v: 5,
    _id: '622ae8d94bee11259a3b1756',
  },
  {
    image: '/uploads/2022-03-12T23:31:14.922Zproduct-2.jpg',
    name: 'sample name 1647127866131',
    price: 30,
    __v: 1,
    _id: '622d2d3a4bee11259a3b17ed',
  },
  {
    image: '/uploads/2022-04-05T04:12:46.469Zproduct-4.jpg',
    name: 'sample name 1649131941926',
    price: 50,
    __v: 1,
    _id: '624bc1a50f91078261ab650d',
  },
  {
    image: '/uploads/2022-04-05T04:39:38.449Zproduct-1.jpg',
    name: 'sample name 1649133566290',
    price: 60,
    __v: 1,
    _id: '624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529',
  },
  {
    image: '/uploads/2022-04-05T04:40:31.140Zproduct-5.jpg',
    name: 'sample name 1649133604220',
    price: 40,
    __v: 1,
    _id: '624bc8240f91078261ab6531',
  },
]

const cartIds = [
  {
    _id: '622ae8d94bee11259a3b1756',
  },
  {
    _id: '624bc1a50f91078261ab650d',
  },
]

const cardIdOnlyArray = cartIds.map(x => x._id)

const result = products.filter(product => !cardIdOnlyArray.includes(product._id))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your first example its likely you forgot to include `x._id` in `!cart_ids.includes(x)`. By looking at the format of the `products` array defined above, that object should have `_id` prop present.

So in first case it should work like

```
let res = products.filter(x => !cart_ids.includes(x._id));
```

And second case doesn't make much sense since you are comparing an array with property (which is called **_id** and its likely, a string or number, and it wont work even if its a reference type such as object or array since comparing those data types with strict operator will always return false)